# Finding the area of region enclosed by two curves

Tags: calculus

> Sketch the region enclosed by the given curves. Decide whether to integrate with respect to $x$ or $y$. Then find the area of the region bounded by $x+y^2= 6$ and  $x+y=0$

this is what i got but it i wrong $6\cdot 3 - 3^3/3 - 3^2/2 - 6\cdot (-2) - (-2)^3/3 - (-2)^2/2$

Comment: Walk me through the steps you took to get to ((6*3)-((3)^3/3)-((3^2)/2))-(6*-2)-((-2)^3/3)-(-2^2)/2

Comment: @marc: I assumed that your (-2^2)/2 in the last term was supposed to be ((-2)^2)/2, i.e., $(-2)^2/2$; let me know if I was wrong.

Comment: Also, I think the points of intersection are (0,0) and (-1/36, 1/6)... I may be wrong tho

Comment: +1 to Silver's first comment. (To borrow from the younger ones' language,) Walkthroughs are just as important in figuring out where a calculation went wrong as in figuring out a game you're playing.

Comment: @Silver: No, they’re $(-3,3)$ and $(2,-2)$.

Comment: Can someone explain how you got those points of intersection? Sry for being noob... But isn't it just a downward sloping line with a right opening parabola with a vertex at the origin...? (I just jumped on this question cuz I was like, "Finally! An easy question I can actually answer!")

Comment: @silver: you read, as I did, "x+y^2= 6 x+y=0" as $x+y^2=0$ and $6 x+y=0$, while Brian spotted it was meant to be $x+y^2=6$ and $x+y=0$.

Comment: ooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooh, gotcha, thanks a lot Henry!

Answer (score 1):

You did essentially everything right.

The parabola and line meet at $y=-2$ and $y=3$. So our area is
$$\int_{-2}^3 (6-y^2 -(-y))\,dy$$
It is clear from your answer that you indeed ended up calculating
$$\int_{-2}^3 (6-y^2 +y)\,dy$$

An antiderivative is given by
$$6y-\frac{y^3}{3}+\frac{y^2}{2}$$

So the answer is
$$\left(6(3)-\frac{3^3}{3}+\frac{3^2}{2}\right)-\left(6(-2)-\frac{(-2)^3}{3}+\frac{(-2)^2}{2}\right)$$

Your next to last term has a sign error.  You have $-\frac{(-2)^3}{3}$ but when you "open" my brackets above, it should turn  to $+$.  (Then, when you expand $(-2)^3$, you get a $-$ again! Minus signs are evil.)

**Minor Comment**: You did not remove all parentheses before integrating.  That left another layer of them, and may have contributed to the minus sign slip.

Comment: 3 is also incorrect, i tried everything, but thanks for your help everyone

Comment: If you mean that the intersection points are not $-2$ and $3$, either your solution book is mistaken, or the equations have not been given correctly. The picture by @Henry shows the $y$-coordinates of the intersection points clearly, and I calculated the intersection points algebraically, we get a simple quadratic equation in $y$. What ultimate answer does the book give?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the sketch.

[image: 2 curves]

You can count the squares and part squares to see the answer is a little over 20.

Comment: Nice! Wish I knew how to do that.

Comment: @André: I used [GeoGebra](http://www.geogebra.org/)

Comment: @André: [Alternatively...](http://fooplot.com/index.php?&type0=0&type1=2&y0=-x&px1=6-s%5E2&py1=s&smin1=-7&smax1=7&xmin=-12&xmax=12&ymin=-7&ymax=7)